# PHP 7.3 FPM Served by Apache Concatenating Errors Messages and Duplicating Them

Tags: php, error-handling, plesk, php-7.3

**Issue:**

Running website on Plesk Onyx Version 17.8.11 Update #43 and running PHP 7.3.2 as FPM application served by Apache. PHP error messages are being duplicated and not displaying errors on a new line.

**Result:**

[Tue Mar 05 11:08:29.409366 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 3293:tid 139890247272192] [client 127.0.0.1:44282] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/script.php on line 522PHP message: PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/script.php on line 524PHP message: PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/script.php on line 522PHP message: PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/script.php on line 524PHP message: PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/script.php on line 522PHP message: PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/script.php on line 524', referer: https://new.domain.tld/webpage.html

**Expected Result:**

[Tue Mar 05 11:08:29.409366 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 3293:tid 139890247272192] [client 127.0.0.1:44282] AH01071: PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/script.php on line 522, referer: https://new.domain.tld/webpage.html

[Tue Mar 05 11:08:29.409366 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 3293:tid 139890247272192] [client 127.0.0.1:44282] AH01071: PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/script.php on line 524, referer: https://new.domain.tld/webpage.html

**Question:**

I recently migrated from PHP 5.6 to 7.3 and the error output to my log file was different. How do I get PHP to not duplicate errors and log them individually?

**Update:**

I was able to remove the duplicated errors by turning `ignore_repeated_source` `On` in the `php.ini`, however the error messages are still being concatenated together.

Comment: You should check out the available `php.ini` settings http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php because I am positive that you will find many more difference between your 5.6 install and the 7.3

Comment: @MonkeyZeus the only new entries were `syslog.facility`, `syslog.filter`, and `syslog.ident`. I initially tried adjusting the `php.ini` settings, but to no avail.

Comment: I never said it's a new setting; this setting has been available since PHP 4.3.0. You should read up on each setting and determine if it is the "magic bullet" for your issue.

Comment: I'm encountering the concatenation issue. Did you find a solution that still allowed you to output to the apache error log?

Comment: I have not found a solution to this concatenation problem after repeatedly searching and experimenting. I am unclear whether this is due to how the FastCGI protocol itself functions, a limitation of Apache's mod_proxy_fcgi and/or PHP-FPM, or some magic switch that I have not discovered. I am forced to conclude that I will need to log PHP errors separately and rework our application monitoring/alerting accordingly.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but with nginx rathar than Apache. So probably an issue with FPM or FastCGI?

Comment: @gronostaj it has been the same from 7.3 to 8.0. On Plesk specifically, I found just grepping the subscription name in `/var/log/plesk-php74-fpm/error.log` or whatever associative PHP version would give me clean logs. I have tried so many things but never a right solution.